# How to send emails with Python and Flask

Tags: python, email, flask, web-applications, smtp

I am working on my website right now and am trying to send a confirmation email when a user creates an account. How can I do this in Python? Can I even do it in Python on my Flask app? I'm really confused right now and could just use some help. Thank you all so much :)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain what you have tried so far. And yes, you should be able to do it using Flask. I would check out [Flask-Mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/).

Comment: I have been trying to use flask-mail, but whenever I do, it says it cannot connect when I use my gmail (only thing I have tried). I was just wondering if there is a better way or if there are any good tutorials because resources seem scarce haha.

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried [Flask-User](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? It says it supports e-mail confirmations. Also, I can't recommend the [Flask MegaTutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) highly enough. That's primarily how I learned to use Flask in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flask_mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) for this purpose

To make it work set parameters this way:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'youremail@gmail.com' # your email
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'your-password' # your password
```

Also go to your [google account security](https://myaccount.google.com/u/security) settings and enable 'Less secure app access’, but google doesn’t really like it and still sometimes you can get errors. In this case just try to play with thaws settings, turn things off and on again, at some point it should definitely work (I’m so convinced, cause this totally works for me)

You also can use the app-specific password in google settings.